# Uploading databases to a server for an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have uploaded the website files using the publishing wizard in Visual Studio. I used FTP to transfer those files. Now I'm not sure how to get my databases hooked up.

I used Code First Migrations in Entity Framework for my databases. I have three databases in my project that have been stored locally. I am trying to add them through cPanel. HostGator is the provider.

I have created 3 MySQL databases in cPanel, but I'm not sure where to go from there and I'm having trouble finding information online.

Comment: You need a Server and a correct ConnectionString. Then you can create the dB again. What is the thing you have problems with? You can't connect to a local db from an external server.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can create the DB in code first migration:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16322232/2072676
hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but I have already created the databases locally, I just don't know how to get them online

Comment: Depends on where the DBs are hosted and what kind of access you have to the DB Server. You could create the databases using MySQL Workbench and then run a script to generate the schema