# Adding New Table Entity Framwork Code First Approach

Tags: c#, entity, frame

That solution does not work in .net core 2 tied to SQL Server 2016.  Original Question: Trying to jump into entity framework, using the "Code First Approach".   I have my new class setup “NewTable” shown below.    I can’t figure out what in the Program Manger Console I need to type to get this table created in my Default Connection String (pointing to a local instance of Sql Server 2016).   The database is working and the user in this .net core 2 web app can register his/her name then log in using that new created account.   Thanks in advance!!

**Default Connection String:**

*"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection" "Server=localhost\RCDSE_Dev;Database=Some Database;User ID=sa;Password=SomePass;"
},*

```
[Table("NewTable")]
public class NewTable
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] //Database generated key
    [Key] //Primary Key
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Manager { get; set; }
}

public class NewTableContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<NewTable> NewTables{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Add-Migration ..` , `Update-Database`. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create database using code first migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718648/how-to-create-database-using-code-first-migrations)

Comment: PM> Add-Migration    then PM>Update-Database

Comment: `Add-Migration [name of migration]` Then yes `Update-Database`

Comment: Do you want your tool to create/update the database automatically when it runs?

Comment: again I'm new to this entity framework.  Where does that migration name come from.. "PM>Add-Migration NewTableContext"  Is that the Context name you specified in the class....

Comment: Sure create on run would be great if its not there.. or update if its changed.   Just trying to learn this ..thanks

Comment: just tried PM> Add-Migration NewTable    PM> Update-Database  and its not showing up..

Comment: none of this is working in .net core 2....

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to the DbContext as below:

```
public class NewTableContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<NewTable> NewTables{ get; set; }

    public NewTableContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
}
```

Comment: This is .net core 2.. that doesn't work     <code>public EngagementContext(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection");
        } </code>

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  Will post a detailed step by step guide for others in the next couple of days.   There are specific things that need to be done in .net core 2 project file that were NOT COVERED in any of the referenced examples by users here.   Thanks for all the help..it got me somewhat pointed in a direction, to find the right direction...lol.